# Derivation and meaning of a long exact sequence of a Homotopy Groups for pairs of spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, exact-sequence, loop-spaces

I read that there are long exact sequences of homotopy groups for each pair of pointed spaces $(X,A,x_{0})$.  Now I know that for an exact sequence that, as the example below denotes $f \text{ and } g$ as maps that $im(f) = ker(g)$:

$$\pi_{n}(A,x_{0})\overset{f}\rightarrow \pi_{n}(X,x_{0})\overset{g}\rightarrow \pi_{n}(X,A)$$

now I know that $im(f)$ is all of $f$ as $A \subseteq X$ and we are just taking basepoint $x_{0}$ to itself.  Thus we would have to have that $ker(g) = \pi_{n}(A,x_{0})$.  I am not sure what is going on, or how to visualize this next part but for is $\pi_{n}(X,A)$ the space X with A as a basepoint?  That somehow A is collapsed?  I know that from the fundamental theorem of isomorphism as applied to exact sequences that $A\overset{f}\rightarrow X \overset{g}\rightarrow X/A$ but am not sure how to show that this holds with the exact sequence of homotopy groups (although they are groups).  So how would I explicitly prove that this is exact?  But again, what is the interpretation of $\pi_{n}(X,A)$?

So that is the first thing I am trying to understand.  Next, I can somehow create a long exact sequence of this.  I know what it is supposed to look like, i.e.:

$$\pi_{n}(A,x_{0})\overset{f}\rightarrow \pi_{n}(X,x_{0})\overset{g}\rightarrow \pi_{n}(X,A) \overset{h_{*}} \rightarrow \pi_{n-1}(A,x_{0})\overset{f}\rightarrow \pi_{n-1}(X,x_{0})\overset{g}\rightarrow \pi_{n-1}(X,A) .... \pi_{0}(A,x_{0})\overset{f}\rightarrow \pi_{0}(X,x_{0})\overset{g}\rightarrow \pi_{0}(X,A)$$

I however don't understand its meaning - especially as it is moving from groups of different dimensions such as some loop space in n dimensions to that of n-1 dimensions etc.

Your insight is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a correction needed to your question: $f(\pi_n(A,x_0))$ is not the same as $\pi_n(A,x_0)$ because for the latter,  homotopies of maps are taken in $A$ whereas in the former they are taken in $X$.

I feel that to understand this type of exact sequence it helps to study a simpler and algebraic example, namely that of the exact sequence of a fibration of groupoids, which models the bottom end of the exact sequence you give, and yields more precise information there.  This notion of fibration is developed in Section 7.2 of [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html). A morphism $p: E \to B$ of groupoids is a **fibration** if for each $x \in Ob(E)$ and each $b$ in $B$ starting at $y= p(x)$ there is an $ e \in E$ starting at $x$ such that $p(e)=b$.  (The original definition with applications  was in the paper R. Brown, J. Algebra 15 (1970) 103-132.) The exact sequence is at 7.2.9, and is of the form

$$ F_x(x) \to E(x) \to B(y) \to \pi_0 F_x \to \pi_0 E \to \pi_0 B,  $$

where $F_x= p^{-1}(y)$ is the fibre of $p$ over $y$. In this situation $F_x(x)  \to E(x)$ is injective so it does not quite model the general situation.

This notion reduces to a **covering morphism** of groupoids if in the above definition of fibration the lifting $e$ is unique, which is equivalent to each $F_x(x)$ is the trivial group.

Comment: Thanks Ronnie - I am guessing your the "R. Brown in the paper mentioned"?  Now I see that $f(\pi_n(A,x_0))$ is a mapping to $\pi_n(A,x_0)$.  Because of the mapping we are in X and not A, hence we are dealing with the homotopies in X.  I am a bit lost on your definition of fibration as I understood a fiber of a point $b \in B$ is the subspace of E which maps to $b$.  I don't understand how $E$ and $B$ relate to $X$ and $A$, but am guessing that somehow we are making a group structure on  $X$ and $A$ which are $B$ and $E$ respectively.  Is this correct?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

To respond to your last comment: "I however don't understand its meaning - especially as it is moving from groups of different dimensions such as some loop space in n dimensions to that of n-1 dimensions etc" perhaps it would be helpful to consider an example.  Consider a disk $D$ with boundary $\partial D = S^1$.  There is a nonzero class in $\pi_2(D,S^1)$ (I am omitting the basepoint to simplify notation), represented by the identity mapping of the disk.  The boundary of this is the class in $\pi_1(S^1)$ represented by the identity mapping of the boundary circle.  So the idea of moving to a different (lower) dimension is actually quite natural.